# Issues on updating text input value into the paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to edit the existing paragraph through text input field. I have written code & some of the things working fine. But the problem is I couldn't update the new values that I have edited. I tried writing event for Update link but the event is not working on this link. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".membership-input").hide();
  $(".membership-edit, .membership-update").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Edit') {
      $(this).text('Update').removeClass("membership-edit").addClass("membership-update");
      //$(".membership-input").removeAttr("disabled").focus().select();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").show();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").hide();
      inputVal = $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").text();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").val(inputVal).focus().select();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").val(updatedVal);
    } else {
      $(this).text('Edit').removeClass("membership-update").addClass("membership-edit");
      //$(".membership-input").attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").hide();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.site-settings>tbody>tr>td {
  border-top: none !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.site-settings>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.site-settings>tbody>tr>td:last-child {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<main class="all-content-wrap">
  <div class="admin-console-wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1>Site Settings</h1>
          <h4 class="mrgn-top-20">Names</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <table class="table site-settings">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Site Name</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p><a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Site Alternate Name</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem.com</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p><a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Legal Name of Business</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem (india) Pvt. Ltd.</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: If you click any of the edit links you get an error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: updatedVal is not defined`

Comment: You aren't defining UpdatedVal - try using inputVal.

Comment: what is in the `updatedVal` i cant see it getting initialized in thecode anywhre

Answer (score 2):

**Seeing your program two problems have been identified.**

---

1. It seems that you have used undeclared **"updatedVal"** variable in the program rather than using the **"inputVal"** which contains the value of the dom (.text()).
2. You have not written any code to update the dom text with the input.val().  So fetch val of input and set it as text of the DOM.

For better understanding I have attached the updated code.

### Updated Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".membership-input").hide();
  $(".membership-edit, .membership-update").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Edit') {
      $(this).text('Update').removeClass("membership-edit").addClass("membership-update");
      //$(".membership-input").removeAttr("disabled").focus().select();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").show();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").hide();
      inputVal = $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").text();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").val(inputVal).focus().select();
    } else {
      updatedVal = $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").val();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").text(updatedVal);

      $(this).text('Edit').removeClass("membership-update").addClass("membership-edit");
      //$(".membership-input").attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".membership-input").hide();
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".site-name").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.site-settings>tbody>tr>td {
  border-top: none !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.site-settings>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.site-settings>tbody>tr>td:last-child {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<main class="all-content-wrap">
  <div class="admin-console-wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1>Site Settings</h1>
          <h4 class="mrgn-top-20">Names</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <table class="table site-settings">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Site Name</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p><a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Site Alternate Name</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem.com</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p><a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>Legal Name of Business</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p class="site-name">Lorem (india) Pvt. Ltd.</p>
                  <input class="form-control input-md membership-input" type="tet">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="link membership-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

*If still you find any issue , feel free to comment.*

Comment: 'Code dump' answers are useless. We are here to educate people, not spoonfeed solutions. Please explain to the OP and any future visitors what the issue is and why your code fixes it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hope, the answer explains in a better way now. Still, if you find it incomplete feel free to comment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @RonitMukherjee - Thank you very much.